# React.js: Get error message despite http response 400

Tags: reactjs, post

I have a scenario wherein if I save a duplicate record in DB, the modal should show the exact error message

POST request using axios:

```
    saveBankMaintenance(optionsBrstn){
        return axios.post(`${API_URL_SAVE_BANK_MAINTENANCE}`, 
            [optionsBrstn]
    )
```

I'm calling this POST request using:

```
const saveBrstn = useCallback(() => {
    ClientMaintenanceService.saveBankMaintenance(optionsBrstn)
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.data.success === "Success"){
        setShowBrstnSaveSuccessModal(true);
        setShowBrstnSaveFailedModal(false);
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
        setShowBrstnSaveSuccessModal(false);
        setShowBrstnSaveFailedModal(true);
    })
  });
```

Saving is OK if its successful

However, when it fails, it goes straight to the `catch` block and I can't set the error message on the state

Is there a way for me to get the json response (containing the error message) alongside the http status response 400?

TIA

Comment: where is the fucntion that sets the state on error?
You can call that function in catch block.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could get the response data in `error` object in the `response` property.

Try this.

```
const saveBrstn = useCallback(() => {
    ClientMaintenanceService.saveBankMaintenance(optionsBrstn)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.success === "Success") {
                setShowBrstnSaveSuccessModal(true);
                setShowBrstnSaveFailedModal(false);
            }
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.response.data); // you can get the response like this
            console.log(err.response.status); // status code of the request

        })
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Did not know this, thanks for sharing.